# Adding onclick to all tel links

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress site. Everything is working perfect and no issues. The only thing i am trying to figure out how to do is track whenever someone clicks on a tel link with the following:

```
<a href="tel:8002221111" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Mobile', 'Click to Call'])">Click here to call us now at 1-800-222-1111.</a>
```

The problem is that i can't add that in my call to action button. I can only use `tel:8002221111`. I know that i can use global javascript but i have no idea how i would be able to change all tel links to add the onclick option.

Any one have any ideas on how to do this or has anyone already done something like this before?

Comment: Are you trying to find all the number and identify them as a phone number ? or you have some wrapper around tel number with class ?

Comment: this is the actual code it shows when it shows the tel link with the number:    <a class="button button_js kill_the_icon" href="tel:8002221111">
<span class="button_icon">
<span class="button_label">8002221111</span>
</a>

Answer (score 8):

This will add the `onclick` event to every `a` tag whose `href` starts with `tel`.

```
$("a[href^='tel']").on("click",function(){
    _gap.push(['_trackEvent', 'Mobile', 'Click to Call']);
});
```

Comment: I am using this for Tealium event tracking. But "a" tag with "tel" click event is firing twice. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with plain JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='tel:']"),
        l = elements.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        elements[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Mobile', 'Click to Call']);
        });
    }
}, false);
```

Compatible with IE9+ and all other modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'a[href^="tel:"]', function() {
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClickToCall', 'CallRequest', 'Mobile', undefined, false]);
});
```

If this works please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: that looks like it would work, but it didn't pick up. not sure if this helps but i just read that wordpress uses jquery in no conflict mode

Comment: just use no conflict instead of "jQuery".

Comment: anyway to do this without jquery and only javascript, for some reason jquery doesn't seem to work with my wordpress at least any custom jquery that i add